# Can I further optimize this Cython code snippet (contains NumPy and a string)?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, cython

I'm a total beginner at using Cython, but I've been following a few introductory tutorials in an attempt to optimize some Python code. I've defined types for all my variables, but `cython --annotate` is showing much more Python interaction than expected. Here's the output, and for those of you who can't view images, the code as well:
[image: output of cython --annotate]

```
+148: cdef int[:] get_hp_lengths(str seq):
+149:     hp_lens_buf = np.zeros(len(seq), dtype=np.intc)
+150:     cdef int[:] hp_lens = hp_lens_buf
 151:     cdef Py_ssize_t start, stop
 152: 
+153:     for start in range(len(seq)):
+154:         for stop in range(start+1, len(seq)):
+155:             if seq[stop] != seq[start]:
+156:                 hp_lens[start] = stop - start
+157:                 break
+158:     if len(seq):
+159:         hp_lens[-1] += 1
+160:     return hp_lens
```

Is this because I'm using `numpy`, and it should be fast enough already? It looks like `str` is also causing Python interaction. Is there a better data type to use, given that I don't know the length of `seq` a priori, but it will contain only `'ACGT'`? Basically, I want to verify that I'm following best practices, and there's not a faster way to implement this.

Comment: You could use integers for `seq`. For example, `0` would mean `'A'`, `1` - `'C'`, etc

Comment: Are you suggesting that because Cython isn't converting the `str` to a C array of `char`s, but it would convert the latter to a C array of `int`s?

Comment: I don't think Cython converts `str` to anything - [it's just Python's string object](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html), so working with plain C arrays of integers could be slightly faster

Comment: Got it, thanks for pointing me to that reference. Looks like it's usually efficient enough, and they recommend to stick with Python `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the python interaction is due to the fact that `len` is a python function and that you call it multiple times. However, it only needs to be calculated once. You can further reduce the python interaction by disabling the index checks for `hp_lens[start]` by means of the [`boundscheck`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#tuning-indexing-further) compiler directive:

```
from cython cimport boundscheck

@boundscheck(False)
cdef int[:] get_hp_lengths(str seq):
    cdef int seq_len = len(seq)
    hp_lens_buf = np.zeros(seq_len, dtype=np.intc)
    cdef int[:] hp_lens = hp_lens_buf
    cdef Py_ssize_t start, stop

    for start in range(seq_len):
        for stop in range(start+1, seq_len):
            if seq[stop] != seq[start]:
                hp_lens[start] = stop - start
                break
    if seq_len > 0:
        hp_lens[-1] += 1
    return hp_lens
```

Comment: Your boundscheck is off, I am not sure if -1 works then.

Comment: @cvanelteren There's no problem using negative indices with disabled `boundscheck`. I guess you confuse the `boundscheck` directive with `wraparound`. Only when disabling the latter Cython is allowed to remove the check for negative indices.

Comment: I just replaced `-1` with `seq_len-1`, and turned `wraparound` off as well

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the best you can do with your code:

- Replace python string with `c_string`
- Replace memory buffers with continuous ones
- ??
- profit!

Here is the edited code

```
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef int[::1] get_hp_lengths(const unsigned char[::1] seq):
    cdef int seq_len = seq.shape[0]
    cdef int[::1] hp_lens = np.zeros(seq_len, dtype= np.intc)
    cdef size_t start, stop
    for start in range(seq_len):
        for stop in range(start+1, seq_len):
            if seq[stop] != seq[start]:
                hp_lens[start] = stop - start
                break
    if seq_len > 0:
        hp_lens[seq_len] += 1
    return hp_lens
```

Which produces the following html
[image]

which looks pretty good!